# checkboxes weird bug on tablets

Tags: css, html, browser, tablet

I am facing weird bug on tablet devices when displaying checkboxes.

html code:

```
<li class='test'>
    <input value="value" name="name" type="checkbox" id="value">
    <label style='display:inline-block;' for="value">value</label>
</li>
```

css:

```
.test {
     display: -webkit-box;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: flex;
     -webkit-box-align: center;
     -ms-flex-align: center;
     align-items: center;
     width: 100%;
     padding: 0 .5rem 0 0;
     margin-bottom: .5rem;
     }
```

Please see at the screenshot of tablet (android based Samsung and similar issue with iPad). The more the size of the label, the smaller is the checkbox.

Please suggest what are the possible solution for this behaviour.

[image]

Comment: Anyone, please specify reason for voting for 'Close'.

Comment: please specify the css code you are using maybe your using `table` layout or `flex` property maybe this is causing this issue. giving the width to the checkbox will solve this issue.

Comment: Sorry for that. I have updated now.

Comment: try to add `width` to your input checkbox

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7wgLb9zh/3/ check this fiddle this will help you.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not know that I had to add width for both input and label. Please post as an answer. I will accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add the `width` to your checkbox `flex` is causing this issue.

check this fiddle [jsfiddle.net/7wgLb9zh/3](http://jsfiddle.net/7wgLb9zh/3) it will help you.